# Generate a PDF from a site running javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pdf-generation

I need a way to generate a pdf-file of a site that runs alot of javascript.. any ideas of how to do it..or is there any package that I can use or something?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Should add that I need to generate this server-side using asp.net.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pdf-download/
You can use this Firefox plugin.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/print-pages-to-pdf/
ann this too

Comment: Use itextsharp free library.

Refer:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Creating_PDF_documents_in.aspx
http://forums.asp.net/t/1199774.aspx
http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/654-simple-way-to-create-pdf-document-using.aspx
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/80/Create-PDFs-in-ASP.NET-getting-started-with-iTextSharp
http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5682/create-pdf-files-on-fly-in-c/

Comment: You have to use office xml library there are libraries called office xml and there is one dll as well itextsharp.dll. This is an open source dll.

Have a visit to this link http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5682/create-pdf-files-on-fly-in-c/

Comment: would this work with a live-site aswell.. what I really would like to do is to be able to set a url that I want to get back as a pdf

Comment: Yes! I guess this will work for live site as well And if the content of the webpage which is present in url comes dynamic then you need to generate pdf in memory stream every time. As for static content 1 time would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it server-side I would recommend iTextSharp or Docmosis, and the Docmosis cloud services could also let you create it by a http post from Javascript).  They both allow your application to create PDF documents with a rich set of features for layout and content.  If you say more about what is in the PDFs you need to create then it might be clearer which you would choose.  Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.